# push не работает на сайте с телефона

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, push-уведомления

я пыталась открыть страницу на Android, но push-уведомление работает только на ПК, а на телефоне - нет, в чем может быть проблема? Как настроить push, чтобы оно работало и на телефоне?

```
function sendNotification(title, options) {
        // Проверим, поддерживает ли браузер HTML5 Notifications
        if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        alert('Ваш браузер не поддерживает HTML Notifications, его необходимо обновить.');
        }

        // Проверим, есть ли права на отправку уведомлений
        else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        // Если права есть, отправим уведомление
        var notification = new Notification(title, options);

        function clickFunc() { alert('Пользователь кликнул на уведомление'); }

        notification.onclick = clickFunc;
        }

        // Если прав нет, пытаемся их получить
        else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
        // Если права успешно получены, отправляем уведомление
        if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification(title, options);

        } else {
        alert('Вы запретили показывать уведомления'); // Юзер отклонил наш запрос на показ уведомлений
        }
        });
        } else {
        // Пользователь ранее отклонил наш запрос на показ уведомлений
        // В этом месте мы можем, но не будем его беспокоить. Уважайте решения своих пользователей.
        }
    }

    sendNotification('Верните Линуса!', {
        body: 'Тестирование HTML5 Notifications',
        icon: 'icon-192x192.png',
        dir: 'auto'
        });
```

Comment: У вас столько проверок стоит...  ни одного alerta не появляется?

Comment: в Android совсем ничего нет, может это как-то связано, что нет https и я тестировала в локальной сети?

Comment: У вас не все ветки кода покрыты `alert'ом`. Попробуйте поставить `alert` после комментария *// Пользователь ранее отклонил наш запрос на показ уведомлений*.

Comment: я добавила alert и появилось предупреждение, что я ранее запретила показ уведомлений, но, в настройках, этого сайта нет в списке запрещенных на показ уведомлений

Comment: может ли быть такое, что нет https и сайт автоматически блокирует уведомления?

Answer (score 0):

Для отображения push-уведомлений понадобился сертификат https. Для мобильных устройств запрещено использовать конструктор Notification. Для решения этой проблемы нужно использовать ServiceWorkerRegistration.showNotification()